# Locating files by inode ID reported by MACOS fsck.apfs

Tags: macos, apfs, fsck

Running diskutil on my intel mac I am getting:

```
Running First Aid on “Macintosh HD - Data” (disk1s1)

Verifying the startup volume will cause this computer to stop responding.

Verifying file system.
Volume could not be unmounted.
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk1s1
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 20088642.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking the encryption key structures.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s1.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Macintosh HD - Data was formatted by diskmanagementd (945.230.6) and last modified by apfs_kext (2142.40.3.0.5).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the document ID tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
warning: inode (id 161782158): has the compression bsdflag, but doesn't have the compression xattr
warning: inode (id 161782158): dataless bsd_flag is set, but the compression xattr is missing
warning: inode (id 172634449): has the compression bsdflag, but doesn't have the compression xattr
warning: inode (id 172634449): dataless bsd_flag is set, but the compression xattr is missing
warning: inode (id 172652700): has the compression bsdflag, but doesn't have the compression xattr
warning: inode (id 172652700): dataless bsd_flag is set, but the compression xattr is missing
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
Verifying allocated space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 appears to be OK.
File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as mounted.

Operation successful.
```

/dev/disk1s1 is my DATA volume mounted on /Volumes/Macintosh - HD

I performed a stat on /Volumes/Macintosh - HD to get the volume id as such:

```
stat /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
16777220 210857069 lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 0 1 "Aug 28 12:59:24 2022" "Aug 28 12:59:24 2022" "Aug 28 12:59:24 2022" "Aug 28 12:59:24 2022" 4096 0 0 /Volumes/Macintosh HD
```

Then tried to use GetFileInfo to see the files generating the above errors:

```
GetFileInfo /.vol/16777220/161782158
GetFileInfo: could not refer to file (-43)
```

I also tried the

```
find / -inum 161782158
```

But again nothing.

Anyone got ideas on how I can locate the files reported by fsck_apfs above?

Thanks

Comment: I just tried to find a file on APFS via its inode number and it worked as expected. Maybe these inodes are in a directory you can't access? Did you try `sudo find /System/Volumes/Data -inum 161782158`?

Comment: Yes..... tried that too... but nothing. I also tried it on other 'known' files and it works... so I am thinking these inodes are in some odd state...thanks for the response though !

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm seeing something very similar where I can't find the file associated with the reported inode.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ls -iR /path-to-disk | grep inode`.
This adds the i-switch (display inode in file listing) and R-switch (list recursively) then pipes the result through whichever inode you're searching for. However, I tried this and it doesn't find any files.